# fibonacci series using lists in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print the fibonacci series using lists in python.
This is my code:

```
T = int(raw_input())
N = [int(raw_input()) for i in range(T)]
N[:] = [x-2 for x in N]
L1 = [1, 1]
L2 = []
for j in N:
    for k in range(j):
        L1.append(L1[-1]+L1[-2])
    L2.append(L1)
print L2
```

Here, T denotes the number of test cases. N denotes the number of elements in the fibonacci series.I need to print the required output of the fibonacci series for each test case.

> ```
> Input: 
> 2
> 4
> 5
> ```

Output for the code above:

> [[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13], [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]]

However the output that I want to print is:

> [1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]]

Please let me know how I should proceed on this

Comment: Out of curiousity - what's the next task you're doing? We've answered the 3 and 5s one, now it appears the Fibonacci one... I'll take a guess primes?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do the projectEuler problems. I am much new to python  .I know that the solutions are already out on net. But, I want to go with my own methodology. Despite me giving the best shot, I am getting stuck. Please let me know if I am not supposed to ask  the questions like these here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't reset `L1`. Try:

```
T = int(raw_input())
N = [int(raw_input()) for i in range(T)]
N[:] = [x-2 for x in N]
L2 = []
for j in N:
  L1 = [1, 1]
  for k in range(j):
    L1.append(L1[-1]+L1[-2])
  L2.append(L1)
print L2
```